# How to determine which pg_restore version to use with a given dump file?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-restore

I get the following error when running `pg_restore`

```
pg_restore: error: unsupported version (1.15) in file header
```

Versions the Docker container (running image `postgres:14.10`) provides

```
root@c33fdb601eab:/# postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Debian 14.10-1.pgdg120+1)
root@c33fdb601eab:/# pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Debian 14.10-1.pgdg120+1)
```

So what does this version `1.15` mean, please? Does it indicate the *.sql dump file version? If so, how do I know which `pg_restore` version use to be able to restore it?

PS: clearly there are many similar posts already, but I didn't find an answer explaining how to match a dump file version to a `pg_restore` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indicates the custom format version. The quickest way I found to find out is do:

`head  <custom_dump_file>`

It should have at the top something like:

`test"14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-1.pgdg22.04+1) 16.1 (Ubuntu 16.1-1.pgdg22.04+1).`

This is not the custom file format it just indicates a 14.10 instance of Postgres was dumped with a 16.1 version of pg_dump. You then know you have to use 16+ version of pg_restore. In other words pg_restore is backwards compatible but cannot restore a file that came from a pg_dump version that is newer then itself.